# What is Calldata tag needed when a function has a string parameter?

Tags: solidity, calldata

I'm using:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

---

I have a function as below in my contract:

```
function test(string a) external{
  a="apple";
}
```

An error shows up saying I need to add "calldata" to the parameter. So, if I do the following the error disappears:

```
function test(string calldata a) external{
  a="apple";
}
```

**Question**: Why do I need to add "calldata" when I use string type as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Explicit data location for all variables of struct, array or mapping types is now mandatory. This is also applied to function parameters and return variables. 
For example, change `uint[] x = m_x` to `uint[] storage x = m_x`, and function `f(uint[][] x)` to function `f(uint[][] memory x)` where `memory` is the data location and might be replaced by `storage` or `calldata` accordingly. Note that external functions require parameters with a data location of `calldata`.
for more [Info](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html)